# Python - Deconstructing a list and making it lower case using .lower()

Tags: python, list, lowercase, deconstructor

Hi I am learning Python and for an assignment, I was asked to deconstruct a list and making it lower case using .lower() method. I am confused on how to change items in my list to lowercase using .lower and would like some help.

Here is my code, I was given this structure and had to fill out the missing areas:

## Deconstructing the list

```
def destructure(lst):
  result=[]    
  for i in lst:
    result.extend(i)
  print(result)
```

## Changing items to lowercase

```
???
```

## Function

```
lc=[['ONE','TWO','THREE'],['FOUR','FIVE','SIX']]
destructure(lc)
```

## Expected Output

```
['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX']
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

I tried using:

```
lower = [x.lower() for x in lst]
print(lower)
```

But this wouldn't work.

Comment: You have 2 nesting levels in your original list, so you should handle both: `[[s.lower() for s in l] for l in lc]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that strings are immutable. Thus, when you call str.lower() or str.upper() you'll need to [re]assign the returned value.

It appears that you want to flatten the list (of lists) and produce both upper- and lower-case versions.

You could do this:

```
def destructure(lst, func):
    rv = []
    for e in lst:
        rv.extend([func(s) for s in e])
    return rv

lc = [['ONE','TWO','THREE'],['FOUR','FIVE','SIX']]

print(destructure(lc, str.upper))
print(destructure(lc, str.lower))
```

**Output:**

```
['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX']
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

Comment: So this seems to point me on the right track, but how would I use this code and get an output of: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']

Comment: seven, eight and nine are not in your original data

Comment: Oh sorry I was looking at another problem, but I have updated my post and put the Expected Output I am supposed to get for this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, your example with flattening the data helped me understand how this problem was wanted to be solved

Comment: @dopewasher Welcome to SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If your input list might have any number of nested lists, then this should do it.

```py
def destructure(lst):
    uc = [ ]
    lc = [ ]
    def destructure(lst):
        for v in lst:
            if isinstance(v, list):
                destructure(v)
            else:
                uc.append(v.upper())
                lc.append(v.lower())
    destructure(lst)
    return uc, lc
    
uc, lc = destructure(lst)
print(uc)
print(lc)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have a list you have a list of lists. Applying **lower()** to x is therefore being applied to a list instead than to a string and will not work, and in fact the interpreter will complain about *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'*.
You have to iterate through all the sublists and apply the operator to each of the strings as follows:

```
def destructure(lst):
    low = []
    up = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            low.append(lst[i][j].lower())
            up.append(lst[i][j].upper())
    return (low, up)


lc=[['ONE','TWO','THREE'],['FOUR','FIVE','SIX']]
low, up = destructure(lc)

print(up)
#output = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX']

print(low)
#output = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

Comment: Have you considered what would happen if *lst = [['ONE','TWO','THREE'],['FOUR','FIVE','SIX','SEVEN']]* ?

Comment: The example of the question had the substrings of the same lenght, however now i generalized the code so that even your case is accounted for. Thank you for pointing out !